# Logout link not working

Tags: links, logout

My logout link is not logging me out. May be I am missing something.

I tried the below links which is generated by `wp_logout_url(site_url())`. But still I am logged in.

> `http://192.168.123.2/mysite/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.123.2%2Fmysite&_wpnonce=24f1683005`

What can be wrong?

**More info :**

Logout link is in custom menu. I check whether if the user is logged out or logged in by using the function `is_user_logged_in()` from within the `function.php` file.

Comment: Not seeing any problem here, might just be some configuration hiccup, like cookies don't get deleted, on your dev environment.

Comment: post your code for adding the link to the menu.

Comment: I noticed, my admin dashboad is signed out. of cource it mean sign out is working. Now what happen is `is_user_logged_in()` is returning `true` even after the user is logged out.